# jQuery - Making a DIV both .draggable and .droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I was toying about on jsFiddle and was wondering at all if it was possible to make an object both `.draggable` and `.droppable`, for example so that I would be able to make it so that `Div.1` could be dropped onto `Div.2` and vice versa.

My jQuery

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({revert: true, snap: 'inner'});
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var one = $(this).html();
        var two = ui.draggable.html();
        $(this).html(two);
        ui.draggable.html(one);
      }
    });
  });
```

and My HTML

```
<div id="draggable droppable">16.00 - 17.00</div></br>
<div id="droppable draggable">13.00 - 14.00</div></br>
<div id="draggable droppable">14.00 - 15.00</div></br>
<div id="droppable draggable">09.00 - 10.00</div></br>
<div id="draggable droppable">07.00 - 08.00</div></br>
<div id="droppable draggable">18.00 - 19.00</div></br>
```

Any ideas anybody? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using classes instead of id's when using them more then once as id's can only be used once
also you cannot use 2 id's on 1 element.

Comment: xD Thank you so much, surprisingly I've been coding for about 5 years and I can't believe that I just made such a rookie mistake... I can't accept the answer yet because StackOverFlow makes you wait a while, but I will in a minute! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i correct your code. problem is you use id, id is unique in html page when we use those id in java script. I replace those id with class.

```
$(function() {
        $( ".draggable" ).draggable({revert: true, snap: 'inner'});
        $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
          drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var one = $(this).html();
            var two = ui.draggable.html();
            $(this).html(two);
            ui.draggable.html(one);
          }
        });
      });

<div class="draggable droppable">16.00 - 17.00</div></br>
<div class="droppable draggable">13.00 - 14.00</div></br>
<div class="draggable droppable">14.00 - 15.00</div></br>
<div class="droppable draggable">09.00 - 10.00</div></br>
<div class="draggable droppable">07.00 - 08.00</div></br>
<div class="droppable draggable">18.00 - 19.00</div></br>
```